# Stuttering on video conference

Tags: audio, skype, video-conference

I am using a Mac Mini with the newest macOS. The Mac Mini itself is also relatively powerful and has 8 GB of memory. It was recently bought (maybe a few months ago).

Yet, whenever I try to use Skype or other video conferencing tool (Zoom, Google hangouts) people report that it sounds choppy, stuttering sometimes, all kind of vocal effects. The video works great though.

I twice changed microphones, and now I am using a specialized USB microphone, but the problems continue.

I can't figure out why this happens. I also tried reinstalling Skype, it didn't help, and it is not a surprise as the problem persists in other videoconferencing apps as well.

The only suspicion I have is that videoconferencing is too compute-intensive for my Mac Mini (hence I mentioned in the beginning that it is new and has 8GB RAM), as the fan starts working really hard when I run Skype, for example.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Have you tried this with a temporary user account to see if the problem continues? The Mini should have enough power to handle this.

Comment: I don't think it is related to that, as I said, it doesn't just happen with Skype

Comment: it is also not related to Internet speed, I believe, it happens with many people, and my Internet speed is very fast (cable connection on a large institution)

Comment: Settings in your own account may be causing an unknown problem. If the problem disappears when a fresh, new user runs the apps, then it is something about your account. If not, it's systemic.

Comment: Do you have SoundFlower installed? (Look for extra input devices in the Sound settings). I had this happen to me, and when I uninstalled SoundFlower my audio went back to normal during meetings.